# Total Task hour not in sync with user story remaining hour

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

the roll-up of tasks does not sum up the remaining amount of work for the userstory. If you go to a specific story and look at the lower level tasks under links they are not in sync with the userstory. we are using visual studio, scrum v2 on tfs 2010.

for ex: if there are 5 task in a user story, out which 1 task hour=8, rest zero. the total task hour sum up (i.e remaining hour) as 144 in user story.

Need help/suggestion/advice

Answer (score 0):

Use a 3rd party tool called [TFS Aggregator](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/)

> This server side plugin for TFS 2010 enables dynamic calculation of field values in TFS. (For example: Dev work + Test Work = Total Work). It supports same work item and parent-child links. It also has support for aggregating string values (ie Children are Done so the parent is Done).